# Programmatically authentication in LifeRay

Tags: authentication, liferay, x509

I'm using LifeRay and need some kind of special authentication: my users have x.509 certificates which are validated by an Apache Webserver. After a successful validation, the user is redirected to Tomcat and in there LifeRay.

Now I want to do the following: get the subject DN of the user's certificate programmatically and log in the LifeRay user that is connected to this DN.

So far, I have the following:

- Created a hook "login.events.pre" where I get the DN from the certificate
- Search the LifeRay DB for a user with this DN (using UserLocalServiceUtil.getUserByOpenId())
- Authenticate user using UserLocalServiceUtil.authenticateByScreenName()

My question now: is that the "best"/cleanest way to do this or should I use other methods for querying the LifeRay DB, authenticating the user etc. For instance, instead of a hook I could create an Ext-Extensions for LifeRay. Additionally, I found some stuff like "com.liferay.portlet.login.util.LoginUtil.login" or User user = PortalUtil.getUser(request); to get a user.

Is there a place in the docu where those questions are answered? The API is not that comprehensive...

Comment: Your way seems to be a cleaner way. Using EXT as you would know is not recommended unless you have no other way since it will be a maintenance and deployment burden.